# android unit test coverage report through Github Actions

Tags: android, unit-testing, github-actions

I execute unit test with github actions.

```
- name: Archive code coverage results
    if: always()
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
    with:
        name: code-coverage-report
        path: ./app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
        working-directory: ./hoge
```

error message shows like this

```
[error]Path does not exist /home/runner/work/hoge/hoge/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/runner/runners/2.169.1/bin/Runner.PluginHost', arguments 'action "GitHub.Runner.Plugins.Artifact.PublishArtifact, Runner.Plugins"'.
```

I'm not sure why github actions can't find the path. Do I set wrong path?
./app/build... is under hoge.

Comment: the path must be wrong somewhere. Try doing a bunch of `- run: ls && pwd` to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its too late for you but may be suitable for others with same aim to upload test results

Option 1: upload only html report without all other JS stuff

Option 2: upload entire directory

```
name: PR_unit_tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  Unit-test:
    name: Run unit tests on PR in main
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with: {java-version: 1.8}
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: ./gradlew test

      - name: Upload html test report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: index.html
          path: app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html

      - name: Upload test report directory
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: testDebugStuff
          path: app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/
```